# How to override label and icon of the button from the form using <fr:buttons>

Tags: orbeon

I am successfully able to overrides the buttons configured with oxf.fr.detail.buttons property. By including them explicitly inside the `<fr:buttons>`

ex.

```
   </fr:section>
      </fr:body>
         <fr:buttons>
              <fr:clear-button/>
              <fr:pdf-button/>
              <fr:close-button/>
          </fr:buttons>
     </fr:view>
```

Now I want to change **Label and Icon** of button from here.
How to achive this if it is possible ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Both the icon and the label are defined in language-specific resources. You'll find more information on how to override them in the [Overriding resources](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/configuration-properties/configuration-properties-form-runner#TOC-Overriding-resources) section of the documentation.

(I could re-explain here how this is done, but really this section of the documentation is a fairly direct answer to your question, so I prefer to just link to it here.)